# A word (other than stationery) to describe a collection of 'paper, journals, books, invitations, wall art'

Tags: books

I am a designer and will be opening a store with 3 sections weddings, home and lifestyle. In all I will be selling wedding stationery suites (wedding invitations, place cards, menus etc) under the wedding section, journals and notebooks under the lifestyle section as well as a selection of wall art for homes.

I am therefore in search for a word that describes a collection of these things. I was going to use 'stationery', however I am aware that the general public would perceive this as referring mainly to office or school supplies.

Any input is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Will _correspondence stock_ do?

Comment: There is no other term "stationery" comprises al the things you mentioned. **Paper craft** would exclude journals and agendas. Either stick with stationery and rely on your customers being able to see that you offer other items beyond **office supplies** or create a new expression.

Comment: I'm not sure that wall art would fall into either stationery or correspondence stock.

Comment: Maybe *paper stock* might do the trick.

Comment: I think this needs some clarity on how the "collection word" is going to be used. Also what does the wall art consist of? If it's simply paper posters then _paper stock_ might be suitable but if it's framed art work (or metalwork or ceramics, etc.) then another term would be needed.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the connection between wedding supplies, general notebooks/stationery, and wall art. Other than "merchandise" or maybe something nearly as vague, e.g. "fancy goods". Maybe if you think more clearly about what links your stock you'll find a connecting term, although it's likely to be a new coinage to some extent.

Comment: What @StuartF said. It doesn't really make sense to ask for a blanket term covering this particular disparate group of "paper-based fancy goods / artwork". Maybe you could pun off "haberdashery", with ***Paperdashery Supplies***

Comment: The Oxford Dictionary of Collocations gives 'wedding stationery' as an idiomatic usage. 'Home stationery' sounds fine to my ears. I see 'wall art' as being non-stationery; the raw materials are usually sold in the crafts departments of large shops.